# Jade condition check at attribute meta tag

Tags: pug

is it possible to do something like following?
if pageUrl is empty then show "a", if not show "c"

layout.jade

```
meta(property='og:url', content='#{pageUrl} == '' ? 'a' : 'c'')
```

index.jade

```
block  vars
    - var pageUrl = someServerUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
meta(property='og:url', content=pageUrl === "" ? "a" : "c")
```

In the layout you can create a block for change the variables before to read, else when you render the view and extends layout, variable has draw into layout before and no change in view.

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  block vars
  head
    meta(property='og:url', content=pageUrl === "" ? "a" : "c")
```

**index.jade**

```
extends layout

block  vars
    - var pageUrl = someServerUrl
```